# Segmentation fault of small code

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to test something and I made a small test file to do so. The code is:

```
void main(){
    int i = 0;
    char array1 [3];
    array1[0] = 'a';
    array1[1] = 'b';
    array1[2] = 'c';

    printf("%s", array1[i+1]);
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

I receive a segmentation error when I compile and try to run. Please let me know what my issue is.

Comment: Your array is not null-terminated. `array1[i+1]` is `char` and not `char*`.

Comment: read compiler warnings. They're useful

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Many of those have to be enabled manually if you're doing this on the command-line.

Comment: ... and that's really a crime.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre do you mean using command line to compile is a crime?

Comment: I mean: the default level of warnings is a crime. Even me I sometimes forget to add `-Wall -Wextra` and miss some stuff

Comment: Good response thank you.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre We all get spoiled by IDEs that have our back.

Comment: My IDE (GPS, yes, unusual) is relying on my project options, which have `-Wall -Werror -Wextra` set, for all users. But Visual Studio has some good default warning level, yes.

Comment: That's true about VS - even OTT for their own purpose. My command line compilation uses a batch file for a consistent approach.

Comment: A batch file? Those still exist? No makefile?

Comment: Yep I use a makefile, but controlled by a batch file. (.bat). I no longer use IDE because for my purposes is sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Answer (score 2):

Strings need to have a NUL terminator, and you don't have one, nor is there room for one.

The solution is to add one more character:

```
char array1[4];
// ...
array1[3] = 0;
```

Also you're asking to print a string but supplying a character instead. You need to supply the whole buffer:

```
printf("%s", array1);
```

Then you're fine.

Spend the time to learn about how C strings work, in particular about the requirement for the terminator, as buffer overflow bugs are no joke.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Good catch, that's another issue.

Comment: err `printf("%s", &array1);` would better be `printf("%s", array1);`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

*Please let me know what my issue is. ?* firstly `char array1[3];` is not null terminated as there is no enough space to put `'\0'` at the end of `array1`. To avoid this undefined behavior increase the size of `array1`.

Secondly, `array1[i+1]` is a single `char` not string, so use `%c` instead of `%s`  as

```
printf("%c", array1[i+1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you get yourself a good book/video series on C. It's not a language that's fun to pick up out of the blue.

Regardless, your problem here is that you haven't formed a correct string. In C, a string is a pointer to the start of a contiguous region of memory that happens to be filled with characters. There is no data whatsoever stored about it's size or any other characteristics. Only where it starts and what it is. Therefore you must provide information as to when the string ends explicitly. This is done by having the very last character in a string be set to the so called null character (in C represented by the escape sequence `'\0'`.

This implies that any string must be one character longer than the content you want it to hold. You should also never be setting up a string manually like this. Use a library function like strlcpy to do it. It will automatically add in a null character, even if your array is too small (by truncating the string). Alternatively you can statically create a literal string like this:

```
char array[] = "abc";
```

It will automatically be null terminated and be of size 4.

Comment: It's not a very *intuitive* language when you have no references, but good books on C are surprisingly small. It's not nearly as complex and thorny as, say, C++.

Comment: Of course. C++ is a 7 headed hydra. C just so happens to have some very well written books on it. One in particular happens to be rather well known and respected. Even if it's not C++ though, navigating the waters of C and its lovely undefined behavior without a guide is surely the path to madness.

Comment: Absolutely. I learned C from two very slender volumes, but they tell you everything you need to know if you work patiently through the chapters. C++ on the other hand I'm still learning even after thirty years of trying, in part because it keeps evolving in leaps and bounds.

Answer (score 1):

When `printf` sees a `"%s"` specifier in the formatting string, it expects a `char*` as the corresponding argument, but you passed a `char` value of the `array1[i+1]` expression. That `char` got promoted to `int` but that is still incompatible with `char *`, And even if it was it has no chance to be a valid pointer to any meaningful character string...